# Always MismatchSenderId error from ASP.net C# while sending notification

Tags: c#, asp.net, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, appserver

I have taken the `applicationID` and `senderId` from Cloud Message tab. But I always get:

```
{"multicast_id":4754956504020103312,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}
```

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
var applicationID = "AIzaS-----------tkDFiyeLE";
var senderId = "59-------7";
string deviceId = TodeviceId;
WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");

tRequest.Method = "post";

tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

var data = new
{
    to = deviceId,
    notification = new
    {
        body = message,
        title = "Pet Pals",
        icon = "myicon"
    }
};

var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = serializer.Serialize(data);
Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));
tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", senderId));
tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

    using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
            {
                String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                string str = sResponseFromServer;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? P.S. Don't you also have to specify the API_KEY? I think it should be added to the URL you are using, and also it should match the senderId.